# Drush Remote Aliases Line Wrapping Different Than Local Line Wrapping

Tags: drush

We are using Drush version 5.9 and Drupal 7.27 and 7.26.

We have a variety of drush aliases, some marked specifically as REMOTE and one for the LOCAL instance.

Example for REMOTE:
$aliases['ALIASNAME'] = array(
   'root' => 'PATH',
   'uri' => 'URI',
   'remote-site' => TRUE,
   'remote-host' => 'REMOTEHOSTDNS',
   'remote-user' => 'DRUSHUSER',
 );

Example for LOCAL:
$aliases['ALIASNAME'] = array(
   'root' => 'PATH',
   'uri' => 'URI',
 );

When we run a drush command for the LOCAL instance, the line wrapping in the output looks as expected.  For REMOTE instances, the line wrapping is different and difficult to interpret.

Example of REMOTE Drush line wrapping:

```
Other        Fusion Starter Lite                Theme   Disabled       7.x-2.0
          (fusion_starter_lite)                                     -beta2
```

Example of LOCAL Drush line wrapping:

```
Other                                  Fusion Starter Lite (fusion_starter_lite)                           Theme   Disabled       7.x-2.0-beta2
```

What can we do to get the REMOTE line wrapping to match the LOCAL line wrapping style?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has brought this up before.  Perhaps it has come up, but I do not remember an incident about it.  In any event, Drush does not pass the COLUMNS information to remote servers, so the remote side defaults to wrapping at 80 columns.

I added a commit to the master branch (Drush 7), [17c18fb331](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/commit/17c18fb33145f29d5a544d0ceb059788948ad2b3), to do this.  I'll also open an issue to discuss backporting to Drush 6.

**UPDATE:**

I also committed this fix to the Drush 6.x branch.  https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/662

Comment: Thank you very much for this information and the fix. We'll look to updating our version of drush to at least 6.